# Drawing not shown using Python Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to run a simple Turtle Graphics file, but no drawing shows up and IDLE asks me what background color you want?
What's wrong with my Python?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to give us some more information before anyone is likely to be able to help you. Can you edit your question show the program you tried to run? Can you show us the full error message you saw in IDLE?

Comment: I was asked this question, and re installation of python solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked this question by a friend, and re installation solved the problem